# Call .dll files in ElectronJS on linux

Tags: c#, node.js, dll, electron, edgejs

I have a problem with using c# .dll files into my ElectronJS app on linux. I know that Electron-Edge helps to run .NET in Node.js on Electron. But if it`s possible to use c# .dll on linux in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Check out compatibility table at https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge - if dll is targeted coreCLR and if linux system has core.net installed, those might work for some. If you're dll isn't targeted to coreCLR, then it's pretty much impossible.